# Mongo Conditional Attributes in find()

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So in meteor I am publishing a collection based on different filters. To make it simple, in my example below I just have two filters, but actually I have more.  I want to be able to just have one Postings.find() and just have the attributes if they are not null greater than one.  How can I accomplish this?  I know I am writing way too much code.  Thanks!

```
Meteor.publish "PagedPostings", (deviceId, colors, capacities) ->
    ##example variables
    #deviceId= "32DLKJF334ALKDJA2"
    #colors = ["blue", "red"]
    #capacities = ["16gb", "32gb",  "64gb"]
    if colors and capacities
        postings = Postings.find(
          deviceId: deviceId
          color:
            $in: filter.colors
          condition:
            $in: filter.conditions
        )
    else if colors
        postings = Postings.find(
          deviceId: deviceId
          color:
            $in: filter.colors
        )
    else if capacities
        postings = Postings.find(
          deviceId: deviceId
          condition:
            $in: filter.conditions
        )
   return postings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```coffee
Meteor.publish 'PagedPostings', (deviceId, colors, capacities) ->
  check deviceId, String
  check colors, Match.Optional [String]
  check capacities, Match.Optional [String]

  selector = {deviceId}
  selector.colorIds = $in: colors if colors
  selector.capacityIds = $in: capacities if capacities
  Postings.find selector
```

This will require that `deviceId` be a string, and that `colors` and `capacities` each be either an array of strings or `undefined`. That seems like a reasonable assumption based on the question but you can easily tweak these based on the actual requirements.

Comment: what if I need to use $in?  condition:  $in: filter.conditions

Comment: In order to give a precise answer, I'll need to know more details. Can you edit your question with exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: Got it. Give the new version a try and let me know if that works.